# Duplicates in findContours method of OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, contour

I am using python openCV library to get the coordinates of contours in a simple image.As I understand the order of the points in the contour will be the order in which findContour() method returns.

But the set of points which findContour() returns has duplicates in it.If the order is retained then how come there are duplicates?

How do I read the output?

Here is the code

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from pylab import plot,show

from PIL import Image


def get_contours(im):
  
  imgray = cv2.cvtColor(im,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
  ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(imgray,127,255,0)
  im2, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

  return im2, contours, hierarchy

def main():
    im = cv2.imread('border.jpeg')
    
    contour_image, contours, hierarchy = get_contours(im)

    contour_points = []
    for pt in contours[1]:
        contour_points.append((pt[0][0],pt[0][1]))
        plot(pt[0][0],pt[0][1])
    
    if len(contour_points)!= len(set(contour_points)):
        print "has_duplicates"
    else:
        print "no duplicates"

main()
```

[image: Here is the image]

Answer (score 4):

The object you're finding the contour of contains some 1 pixel wide "bottlenecks", so that edges on the opposite sides share a vertex.

It's best to illustrate this with a picture.

Imagine this situation in a 4x5 pixel image:

[image]

Let's run a short script to find the contour of this:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[0,0,0,0],[0,0,1,0],[0,1,0,0],[0,0,1,0],[0,0,0,0]],dtype=np.uint8)
>>> _, contours, _ = cv2.findContours(a,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
>>> print contours
[array([[[2, 1]],
       [[1, 2]],
       [[2, 3]],
       [[1, 2]]])]
```

If we draw this in, it becomes quite obvious:

[image]

Comment: But According to your arrow marks shouldn't the array end with [2,1].Why is that point appearing only once?

Comment: @MadhuriPalagummi The last edge (going between the last and first vertex) is implicit (the contour is always closed), so that vertex is not duplicated. (AFAIK this is not documented well, but confirmed from source code and experience)

Comment: So acc to this, every point except the first point should be listed twice?
Is that right?

Comment: And also is the start point always an end point(in case the contour is a line like in this image)?Or is the topmost point?

Comment: First comment: No. Notice that the number of occurrences of each point in the list corresponds to the number of arrows drawn in the image. | Second comment: Yes, the starting point is also implicitly the ending point. e.g. to describe a contour of a square, you'd list each corner once. I have not studied the algorithm in detail to be able to say whether it is always the top-most point.

Comment: The [older documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#findcontours) contains a reference to the original paper describing the algorithm. So does the [new one](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga17ed9f5d79ae97bd4c7cf18403e1689a). Source you can download, or find on [github](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/954082d891cccf3c6bd248ebb4049197c0d029f7/modules/imgproc/src/contours.cpp#L1895).

Comment: Masek Can you please tell me what tool you have used to create the above images(the ones you used in your answer for explanation)

Comment: @MaPY Just a regular raster graphics editor (in this case Paint.Net). There would be many other alternatives, but this was a simple enough illustration to throw together by hand.

Answer (score 0):

It has been a long time, but also...

Maybe you can use parent and child level that exist in the hierarchy variable.
It can be useful for filtering contours in the same level.
You can access a shape's parent number by an index like this.

```
hierarchy[0,cn,3]
```

and cn is index of the contours.

complete information [HERE](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d9/d8b/tutorial_py_contours_hierarchy.html)